# Dynamic Tab Control which can hold User Controls

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol

I want to create a Tab Control which can hold for multiple User Controls.

```
<TabControl Padding="0">
    <TabItem Header="{x:Static p:Resources.Scheduler}" 
             Visibility="{Binding ShellService.IsSchedulerEnabled,
                                  Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}">
        <ContentControl>
            <ContentControl.Style>
                <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsVisible" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Content" 
                                    Value="{Binding ShellService.LazySchedulerView.Value}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ContentControl.Style>
        </ContentControl>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

The xaml is only for 1 tab item, which control by ShellService.IsSchedulerEnabled and the content is ShellService.LazySchedulerView.Value.

My problem here is that if I want to create a new TabItem, I have to create a new TabItem tag in the xaml.

How can I create a dynamic tab control to hold more than 1 tab item without specifying 'Value' in ContentControl.

```
public interface IShellService : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    object ShellView { get; }

    bool IsSchedulerEnabled { get; set; }

    Lazy<object> LazySchedulerView { get; set; }
}

[Export(typeof(IShellService)), Export]
internal class ShellService : Model, IShellService
{
    private object _shellView;
    private bool _isSchedulerEnabled;
    private Lazy<object> _lazySchedulerView;

    public object ShellView
    {
        get { return _shellView; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _shellView, value); }
    }

    public bool IsSchedulerEnabled
    {
        get { return _isSchedulerEnabled; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _isSchedulerEnabled, value); }
    }

    public Lazy<object> LazySchedulerView
    {
        get { return _lazySchedulerView; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _lazySchedulerView, value); }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Style` for this `TabItem`. I created some example for you. You should change `Bindings` to your own. And you should create `ObservableCollection` of `ShellService`s and bind it to the `TabControl`. I hope this helps.

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Objects}">
    <TabControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TabItem" x:Key="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Header}"></Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsVisible" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding Text}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TabControl.Resources>
</TabControl>
```

**Update**

ViewModel Sample

```
public class OwnObject : ViewModelBase
{
    private string _text;

    public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set { _text = value; NotifyPropertyChanged( "Text" ); }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    #endregion
    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged( String info )
    {
        if ( PropertyChanged != null )
        {
            PropertyChanged( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( info ) );
        }
    }
}
```

I bound these objects to `TabControl`.

```
private ObservableCollection<OwnObject> _objects = new ObservableCollection<OwnObject>();
public ObservableCollection<OwnObject> Objects
{
    get { return _objects; }
    set { _objects = value; NotifyPropertyChanged( "Objects" ); }
}
```

Comment: How about the tab name?

Comment: Oh sorry, you're right, there is some problem with header. So I updated the answer, you should use `Style` instead of `ItemTemplate` and should add `Header` property into `ShellService` model to bind it to the header. Of course you can create more complicated header by adding some template with bindings for it.

Comment: Can you give example on how to bind the objects from ShellService to the xaml? I failed to do that... My tab content shows the class object's name.

E.g: MyApp.Objects.TabObject

Comment: You should realize `NotifyPropertyChanged` for props in the `ShellService` and set appropriate `DataContext` for `TabControl`. Updated the answer

Comment: And what actually contains the collection `LazySchedulerView`?

Comment: @bars222, in WPF, we work with *data* objects, not UI objects, so there should never be a collection of UI objects. Instead, we have a collection of data objects - each object should contain properties to data bind to the UI objects, so a `Name` property for example. Then you need a `DataTemplate` that binds the `Name` property to whichever UI field you want. The result is that when you add a data item into the collection, a new UI object will be added into the UI. See the [Data Templating Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms742521(v=vs.100).aspx) page on MSDN for further help.

Comment: @Sheridan yes, you're right. So TS should create some templates for content and use `TemplateSelector` or something else.

Comment: The best option is often to put the `ControlTemplate` into a `Style` and to simply omit the `x:Key` directive on the `Style`. Without an `x:Key` directive set, the `Style` will be implicitly set on all objects of the same type as the `Style`.

Comment: @bars222 LazySchedulerView is a Lazy<object> to hold ViewModel object to initialize the UI. For my project, I have public class SchedulerViewModel : ViewModel<ISchedulerView>, and My xaml CS file is public partial class Scheduler : UserControl, ISchedulerView.

Comment: So you should read Data Templating Overview, as Sheridan said, and display `TabItem` content by creating some templates for it.